# how to read one field from one record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, recordset

I know I'm over thinking this, but I want to check a single value/field within a single record. For instance, I want to know if the value of the "closedDate" field in the record with the primary key of 33 is null or not.

I was thinking something like:

```
dim db as DAO.Database
dim rs as DAO.Recordset
set db = CurrentDb
set rs = db.OpenRecordset("record_holdData")

If not isNull(rs.Fields("closedDate")) then
     'do nothing
Else
     'add a close date
End If
```

But I don't think this is right. It doesn't specify the record number. In the application, the form is opened by being bound to the record in question, but I don't think `CurrentDb` takes that into consideration and rather references the entire table.

So my question is, how do open the recordset in this fashion and reference this field in that particular record only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You found the answer you wanted, but I would use the [DLookup Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx) instead.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strWhere As String
Dim varClosedDate As Variant
Set db = CurrentDb
strWhere = "id = 33"
varClosedDate = DLookup("closedDate","record_holdData",strWhere)
If IsNull(varClosedDate) = True Then
    'use today's date as closedDate
    db.Execute "UPDATE record_holdData Set closedDate = Date() WHERE " & strWhere
End If
```

Comment: I didn't do a comparison test.  With an index on the id field, both your recordset solution and this one should be fast.  If I had to guess, I would choose DLookup as faster since it doesn't include the overhead to create the recordset object.  However, I doubt you'd notice a difference without a precise test method.  If performance is critical in your situation, test them both.

Answer (score 3):

I was under the impression that the argument for the .OpenRecordset() method was to be a table name only. But it turns out you can send it a query too:

```
set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from record_holdData where id = 33")
```